# PHP embedded image not showing on web browser

Tags: php, email

I'm sending an e-mail newsletter in PHP. Inside the PHP I have something like

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
set_time_limit(0);
$to='123@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test';
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: 123@gmail.co.id\r\nReply-To: 123@gmail.co.id";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering

include ("contents.php");

$message = ob_get_clean();

//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

and this is contents.php file

```
<?php 
// A few settings
$img_file = 'tes.jpg';

// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_file));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img_file).';base64,'.$imgData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
?>
```

When I open the email with android smartphone, the image is being displayed. However, when I open it with web browser or outlock, no image is shown. I'm not sure if it's about the proxy that Gmail uses for security reasons or if it's something else. Either way, I'd like to know if anyone ever came across this and if so, how it was solved.

Comment: Well, the simple answer is: 
Host the image in some server and put the complete url to the file in the src of the image.

Comment: i have upload the image into google drive and create shareable link, stil not wortk. any idea @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi

Comment: Some email programs hide email images and shows a link to display images. Check to see if you see a link like this.
In my e-mails I'm used to include alt description in the images and links whit a description like "Follow this link if you can't see images in this e-mail". Take care to not use the word "click" if you don't want e-mails programs putting your e-mail in spam folders.

Answer (score 0):

**How to investigate**.

It's possible Gmail is prepending the src attribute of the img tag with its CDN endpoint. To verify what is actually in the src attribute, select the image element and inspect it in developer tools:

[Image in Chrome Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCnG3.png)

It may look something like `https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/...#data: image/gif...` which is not a valid URL.

**Plan A**.

If Gmail is looking for a URL to the file and not a data URI, you could [upload the file to Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html) and point to it in the src attribute.

**Plan B**.

Try this:

```php
echo '<div style="background: url('.$src.') no-repeat left center;">';
```

Instead of:

```php
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```